# Kentico 13: Page Builder Widgets: Restrict usage for User Role

Tags: kentico

I've tried to find some info on this in the official Kentico 13 (.Net Core) Documentation without success. I am wondering if there is a way to restrict the use of page builder widgets by user role (either allow or deny widget usage for role). Thanks! -Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a package created by MVP DevTrev that should handle this for you.  I'd recommend checking this package out.

https://github.com/KenticoDevTrev/XperienceCommunity.WidgetFilter

Comment: Thank you! That looks like it will do exactly what I need. I appreciate the help. -Dave